# Munich I gates?

Tags: short-connections, lufthansa, muc

I cannot seem to find the gate I20 depicted on the MUC termial map.
I am flying from Tel Aviv, Israel to Cluj,Romania connecting through MUC. How much time required to connect arriving LH681 from TLV gate I20 connecting to LH 1668 H39 Cluj, Romania.

Comment: Where do you see gate I20? Are you sure it's not L20? Regarding past flights I see gate H4 listed for LH681.

Comment: @JJJ [FlightAware currently lists](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/DLH681/history/20190510/0355Z/LLBG/EDDM) gate I20 for the flight departing in an hour and a half from now.

Comment: @ZachLipton sure, and they list [I4](https://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/DLH681/history/20190509/0435Z/LLBG/EDDM) for yesterday's flight but that doesn't make it true. [Flightstats lists gate H4 for the same flight](https://www.flightstats.com/v2/flight-tracker/LH/681?year=2019&month=05&date=09&flightId=999212652). The latter is more plausible as the [airport map](https://www.munich-airport.com/airport-map-261352) lists gates H, but not gates I.

Comment: I agree. FlightAware clearly lists special codes for Munich, since another day's flight is listed as M22 (same in [FlightStats](https://www.flightstats.com/v2/flight-tracker/LH/681?year=2019&month=05&date=06&flightId=998875041)), and Munich doesn't have M gates either. It's possible some of those represent remote stands, from which passengers are bused to the terminal, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm also relatively sure the I and M gates are actually at the remote stands, where you take a bus from the stand to the terminal. At MUC they are covered so you are never exposed to rain or snow.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I frequently fly in/out of MUC on smaller regional jets, and for those the transfer between bus and plane isn't covered in any way. Those are always from G-gates, so might be a different situation that OP's.

Answer (score 3):

I20 refers to a "remote stand", where you will need to then catch a bus from the plane to the terminal.  Munich Airports website confirms this, showing the plane arriving at "Gate REMOTE" :

[image]

As far as connection times, Munich is one of (if not THE) best airport in the world for short connections presuming both flights are on Lufthansa, with many flights having a 30 minute minimum connection time.

Israel and Romania are both (currently, see below) outside of the Schengen zone, which means there is generally no need to clear immigration between flights - and most likely also no need to re-clear security when coming from Israel.  In the even of a short connection it's not uncommon for Lufthansa staff to meet the inbound flight at a remote gate and take passengers via car or mini-bus directly to their connecting flight - especially if it's also leaving from a remote stand.

If you are changing airlines, or booking on multiple tickets, then it's always a good idea to leave additional time between flights.

(Note that Romania is due to enter the Schengen area agreement, potentially as early as later this year.  That would change this answer as you would need to go through immigration before making it to your connecting flight, which would add additional time)

Comment: According to another source (https://www.mucforum.de/threads/ausbau-muc-satellit-zum-t2-people-mover-erweiterung-vorfeld-ost.32878/page-67), I gates seem to be gates on level 6 (you can actually see the walkway in the map at https://www.munich-airport.com/airport-map-261352), which are only used for certain unclean arrivals (unclean from a security perspective).

Comment: At the moment FlightStats doesn't show any arrival gate anymore, so it's totally possible that I20 was an error in the data.